# A simple convergent integral but not absolutely convergent.

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Anybody knows a simple example for convergent function but not absolutely convergent?

( simple = easy )

Thanks for coments!!!

Answer (score 3):

Probably the simplest is $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}x\,dx.$$

Comment: You should note you should integrate by parts to show convergence.

Comment: :( That's the usual example. I was thinking in a very simple example, in the sense that is very easy to show this properties. Thanks for your coment. :)

Comment: Well, we can easily write down a step function on $[0,\infty)$ whose integral is $\sum (-1)^{n+1}\dfrac 1n$. You're going to have to accept one or the other ;)

Comment: @YotasTrejos, it is a simple example. But integrating by parts, you are able to show that the integral converges without having to determine it's value.

Answer (score 2):

Choose your favorite decreasing sequence $\{a_n\}$ of nonnegative numbers such that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n$ does not converge, and define the function

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} a_1 :& 0 \le x < 1 \\-a_2:& 1 \le x < 2 \\
a_3 :& 2 \le x < 3 \\
-a_4 :& 3 \le x < 4 \\
\vdots \\
(-1)^{n + 1} a_n :& n-1 \le x < n \\
\vdots\end{array}\right.$$

Then it follows that

$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x) = a_1 -a_2 + a_3 - a_4 + \dots $$

converges, while

$$\int_0^{\infty} |f(x)| = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \dots $$

does not.

Comment: Notice I tried giving this to the OP in my comment ...

Comment: @TedShifrin You're right, and the comment precedes my answer. If you'd like to make your comment an answer, I can remove this.

Comment: Nah. I don't think the OP will accept either ;)